# PHP to Ruby: Parsing the Date

Tags: php, ruby, date

So in PHP I have some code that extracts the day, month and year as an integer with something like this:

```
// Grab the Date
    $date = date("mdy");
    $day = (int) substr($date, 2, 2);
    $month = (int) substr($date, 0, 2);
    $yr = (int) substr($date, 4);
```

I'd like to do the same in Ruby.  And I thought I'd found the answer with

```
# Grab the Date
    now = Date.new(Time.now).to_date
    date = Date.parse(now)
    day = date.mday
    month = date.mon
    yr = date.year
```

I've tried variations on this theme and every time it fails with

> private method `to_date' called for Tue Aug 14 01:16:00 -0600 2012:Time (NoMethodError)

I'm sure the answer is somewhere on the web but I'm not putting the right question to Google because I haven't found it.  I've only been coding in Ruby off and on for a few months and I imagine it is something simple.  So what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
now = Time.now

day = now.mday

month = now.mon

yr = now.year
```

By the way, you can do that more cleanly, without the `substr()` operations, in PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime;

$day = (int) $date->format( 'j' );

$month = (int) $date->format( 'n' );

$year = (int) $date->format( 'Y' );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in my current app. I haven't tested @Catnapper's suggestion but I like it as well. I keep forgetting you can extend classes like that in Ruby. As far as the PHP portion goes... I figured my code was about as lean as possible - a single 8 char string for the date and substr for extraction. I figured PHP had something like the class you use. However, what you are doing I assume would take more memory and CPU time. The difference is probably negligible but I tend to run hundreds of concurrent tasks so I try to keep things small where I know how to.

Comment: Yeah, that's cool that you can dynamically modify classes in Ruby. I might do it a bit differently in PHP than what you had in the first place (not sure what the context is). But I think what I suggested is a cleaner way to end up with the vars you wanted. Not sure about CPU (I could see it going either way). Might consume a bit more memory, though you could just trash the object after extracting the values: `unset( $date )`. I'd imagine the difference on both counts would be negligible anyway in many situations, and far outweighed by the more elegant code, but I don't know your specifics.

Comment: I think the resource issue is negligible in this instance. It's more a matter of habit. That said, I usually try to write code that is robust and easily read. In most instances I wouldn't use a substr command without an associated comment like 'extracting such and such from'. In this case the variable names speak for themselves pretty well.  And, I would guess, the difference in resource usage is minimal if even measurable. So then we are just down to preferences in coding style. - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'    
def date_to_array date = Date.today
  [date.year, date.mon, date.mday]
end
```

Or maybe, if you're using it all over the place in your app, extend Date:

```
require 'date'
class Date   
  def to_a
    [self.year, self.mon, self.mday]
  end
end
```

Comment: I gave you an up vote but the answer. I like this suggestion but it isn't quite what I want in this piece of code. Thanks for the reminder that I can extend classes in Ruby.

Comment: @Gabe I considered suggesting other formats for the data in PHP, but decided to just replicate the vars you were using. One idea, similar to what @Catnapper has here, would be `$date = explode( "-", $date->format( 'j-n-y' ) )`, but if going to the trouble of defining a method I'd rather return an assoc array (hash). You could do this though: `$date = array_combine( array( 'day', 'month', 'year' ), explode( "-", $date->format( 'j-n-y' ) ) )`. PHP's `getdate()` would be perfect, except that it doesn't have a TZ param and states values in local time (ugh). Too bad no equiv. method on `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot you can do with Date manipulation, seek on the [**Documentation**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) for more! But please don't use ruby with accent :)

```
require 'date'

Date.new(2001,2,3).year
#=> 2001

Date.new(2001,2,3).yday
#=> 34 Returns the day of the year (1-366)

Date.today.day
#=> 14

date = Date.new(2008, 12, 22)
date.day
#=> 22
date.month
#=> 12
date.year
#=> 2008

Date.new(2001,2,3).strftime '%Y'
#=> "2001"
```